# What does $\psi_j(r_i)$ mean?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, electrons, hamiltonian

I have a mean-field Hamiltonian for N electrons. The mean-field potential felt by electron $i$  at position ${\bf r}_i$ is given by

$V^{(i)}_{int}({\bf r}_i)=\sum_{j\ne i}|\psi_j({\bf r}_i)|^2$

I can understand why this is the case. However, I need to clear up my understanding of the term $\psi_j({\bf r}_i)$. Is it simply the wavefunction of the $j^{th}$ electron at position ${\bf r}_i$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **key idea** in the mean field approach is taking into account the contribution, to the potential(the **cause**; see below) at each point ${\bf r}$, of the complete electronic configuration. By electronic configuration, we mean the probability density distribution of each of the one electron states $|\psi_j({\bf r}^')|^2 $. So the **cause** of the $j^{th}$ electron(at ${\bf r}^'$) "on" `the' electron at  ${\bf r}$ is given by

$u({\bf r}) = -e \frac{|\psi_j({\bf r}^')|^2}{|{\bf r} - {\bf r}^'|}$.

Hence the total **cause** would be integrating over all the possible positions ${\bf r}^'$ of the $j^{th}$ electron and summing over all the states $j$ **including**  'the' electron which feels the  effect. This total **cause** is used then to deduce the wavefunction of `the' electron using Schr\:odinger equation (the **effect**).

This may be confusing as we are including the wavefunction of the interested electron (the **effect**) in calculating what could be the possible **cause** "on" it to have that **effect**. This is the **crux** of the mean field approach where effect **feedbacks** the cause until we reach at a 'self-consistent' description of the cause-effect process! (**self-consistent** description is the physics lexicon used for this process.)

Some **caveats** : While integrating over all possible ${\bf r}^'$ we encounter a singularity when ${\bf r}^' = {\bf r}$. This is dealt with what is called "self-interaction" term and correction. I dont have good understanding of this.